# Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have a python script which everytime a wait_for_page call is made it writes the time it took to wait for the page to a database. The query is below:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    connect = conn.cursor()
    params = {'build': self.tc.tag, 'page': unicode(self), 'object_id': self.object_id, 'page_header':
              self.page_header, 'interval': t.interval, 'timestamp': timestamp}
    query = u'INSERT INTO page_load_times (build, page, object_id, page_header, elapsed_time, date_run) ' \
            'VALUES (%(build)s, %(page)s, %(object_id)s, %(page_header)s, %(interval)s, %(timestamp)s)'
    connect.execute(query, params)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Occasionally, when this runs, I get an error which says:

```
 "Failed processing pyformat-parameters; %s" % err)
 ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' 
 object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'
```

I know what is causing this, just uncertain how to go about fixing it. The `'page': unicode(self)` param occasionally gets a list as a result.

In an attempt to fix this, I tweaked the above script to extract the list into a string, with the following:

```
    page_list = u'{}'.format(self)
    page_results = "('%s')" % "','".join(page_list)
    params = {'build': self.tc.tag, 'page': page_results, 'object_id': self.object_id, 'page_header':
              self.page_header, 'interval': t.interval, 'timestamp': timestamp}
```

When I run this, the error I am getting now is that the data is too long for the field. I debug it, to find that my page results has each character parsed out individually looking like so:

```
u'(\\'A\\',\\'p\\',\\'p\\',\\'M\\',\\'a\\',\\'i\\',\\'n\\',\\'M\\',\\'e\\',\\'n\\',\\'u\\',\\':\\',\\' \\',\\'N\\',\\'o\\',\\'n\\',\\'e\\')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to do the following, which takes the page_header and if it is in the instance of list to make that list a string:

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    connect = conn.cursor()
    page_list = u'{}'.format(self)
    page_header_list = u'{}'.format(self.page_header)

    if isinstance(page_header_list, list):
        page_header_list = ', '.join(page_header_list)[0:100]

    params = {'build': self.tc.tag, 'page': page_list, 'object_id': self.object_id,
              'page_header': page_header_list, 'interval': t.interval, 'timestamp': timestamp}
    query = u'INSERT INTO page_load_times (build, page, object_id, page_header, elapsed_time, date_run) ' \
            'VALUES (%(build)s, %(page)s, %(object_id)s, %(page_header)s, %(interval)s, %(timestamp)s)'
    connect.execute(query, params)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DarthOpto, you gave me lots of light. I solved it by putting `srt` around the variable:

```
params = {'build': self.tc.tag, 'page': srt(page_list),'object_id': self.object_id,
          'page_header': srt(page_header_list),'interval': t.interval,'timestamp': timestamp}
```